# When I add a subdivision modifier and smooth my model I get artifacts. Modeling a human head. Blender 2.80

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm new to the Blender forum and 3D modeling in general. I am using Blender 2.80 (2019-05-03). I have followed a tutorial in order to model a head. When I add a subdivision modifier and smoothing I get these strange artifacts (see pics). Has anyone seen this and would you have any idea what's happening and how to fix it and avoid it in the future? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much!

Blend file: [HeadTutorial.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vQTUI8lSsvjKlvkWizR-ydXcPuvM0K4W/view?usp=sharing) Thanks again!

[image: After subdividing twice and smoothing.]

[image: Original model before subdividing and smoothing.]

[image: Model after subdividing.]

[image: Model after subdividing and smoothing.]

[image: Side View.]

Comment: Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vQTUI8lSsvjKlvkWizR-ydXcPuvM0K4W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it looks like you have a problem of normals that you need to recalculate, go in Edit mode, select all and shift N

Comment: @moonboots that seems to have fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) answered my question correctly. Shift + N is the "Make Normals Consistent" shortcut.

Blender 2.80 Normals documentation: [Normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html)

Here is the "fixed" model after implementing the fix:
[image]

Thanks for the help, @moonbots!